# The set $\{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$, where $n \geq 5$, can be divided into two subsets so that the sum of the first is equal to the product of the second

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

A peer of mine showed me earlier today this problem, taken from a 7th grade math contest :

> Let $A=\{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$; (where $n \geq 5$) prove that $A$ can be divided into two disjoint subsets such that the sum of the elements in the first subset is equal to the product of the elements in the second subset.

This has been puzzling me for 15 minutes already, but I'm sure there's a simple, straight-forward way to do it since it's a 7th grade problem, albeit I can't see it.

Can anyone shed some wisdom here ?

Comment: $3=1+2$; $4\cdot2\cdot1=5+3$; $6\cdot3\cdot1=7+5+4+2$

Comment: $n = 5$ works; you get $3+5=1\cdot2\cdot4$; $n=6$ gives $3+4+5=1\cdot2\cdot6$

Comment: The problem actually does ask for a proof . Math is taken quite seriously in my country, those contests are more than tough

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Going by the assumption that for an odd $n$ the product of $1, (n-1), (n-a)$ is equal to the sum of the rest of the numbers, we have
$$
1(n-1)(n-a) = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} - 1 -(n-1) - (n-a)
$$

solving this gives $a=\frac{n+1}{2}$

Now for odd $n \ge 5$, we have
$$n-a = \frac{n-1}{2} \ge 2$$ 
Therefore the numbers $1, n-1, n-a$ are distinct.

A similar assumption for even $n$ with $1, n, (n-a)$ gives
$$
1*n(n-a) = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} - 1 -n - (n-a)
$$
and the solution is $a=\frac{n+2}{2}$

And for even $n \ge 6$ we have
$$n-a = \frac{n-2}{2} \ge 2$$
And therefore the numbers $1, n, n-a$ are distinct.

Comment: We need to know why? (1) How many items to move? (2) Which to move. I disagree to assume there must be 3 items, and 1 and (n-1) must be within the choices. Plus we do not know if there are multiple solutions. Need to proof.

Comment: @PdotWang:  we were just asked to show that there is one solution, not to show how many there are.  benji has exhibited a solution.  (ed df)

Comment: Why are we able to make the assumption that for an odd $n$ the product of $1, (n-1), (n-a)$ equals the sum of the rest of the numbers?

Comment: @Asker We don't assume it, we prove it.

Comment: @Jack M But it says we assume it in the proof above, in the first line. I'm just wondering why that assumption is intuitive/true. More specifically, can you please explain the reasoning of the first 3 lines of the proof if it's not too much trouble?

Comment: @Asker Basically, he just means "Let's try something simple." My answer was the same - I first tried looking for a pair, and then a triple. Since $ab+a+b+1=(a+1)(b+1)$, I realized the easiest triple might be of the form $\{a,b,1\}$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks, this was helpful- but how does one know  that all cases where $n \ge 5$ can be represented in the form $ab+a+b+1$? Also, in the answer, why is it necessary/useful to have $(n-1)$ as one of the three numbers chosen when $n$ is odd, as opposed to something else? Similarly, why is $n$ chosen as one of the three when $n$ is even? I'm guessing it's because we want to have an even term in both of those somehow, but why? And why must it be $n$ or $(n-1)$, as opposed to some other, lesser even term? (Please help me! D:)

Comment: You are misreading what the answer is. The product of the elements of $\{1,a,b\}$ is $ab$. The sum of the other ones is $n(n+1)/2 - (1+a+b)$. So you need $(a+1)(b+1)=ab+(1+a+b)=n(n+1)/2$. But we have obvious factorization of $n(n+1)/2$ depending on whether $n$ is even or odd.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Can you go into your last sentence in more detail? I think I understand the brunt of the proof now, but I still don't get why this means that we choose $a$ to be $n$ or $(n-1)$ depending on if it's even or odd. (I'm pretty bad at this so I sometimes have no idea what to look for, or even what I'm looking at)

Comment: @Asker Have you ever seen someone solve a differential equation by saying "Assume the solution is of the form $e^{at}$", and then find an $a$ that works? It's the same idea here - you assume the solution is of a specific form, then you use that to deduce what the exact solution must be, and that it does indeed work.

Comment: @JackM Sorry, my phrasing was ambiguous now that I think about it. I wanted to know how he intuitively knew to try those three terms $1, (n-1), (n-a)$ in the first place instead of others, not so much about how he proved it worked in retrospect (although that too was confusing to me, Thomas more or less cleared that part up). The algebra and proof otherwise made sense- I just wanted to see how the intuition worked. Specifically, why does he choose $(n-1)$ for odd n and $n$ for evens, as opposed to some lesser even number? The meaning of the last sentence of Thomas's explanation was lost on me.

Comment: @Asker I thought about those sets for $n=5,6,7,8$ and noticed a pattern. The next step was to prove that it actually works.

Comment: @benji Thanks, but can you be more specific in how you thought about the sets that allowed you to notice the pattern? Like, did you write out the $n$s and their sums, and what did you do from there?

Comment: @Asker I meant I just tried to solve for $n=5,6,7,8$. So for example for $n=5, 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 4 = 3+5$. I noticed that for $n=5,7$ the product is made with $1,n-1$ and another number and for $n=6,8$ the product is $1,n$ and some other number. The rest is in the answer..

Comment: @benji Ah, I see now. Thanks

Answer (score 13):

You can always do it with the product being three elements, one of them $1$.

$$1+2+3+4+\cdots +n = n(n+1)/2$$

Find $a,b$ so that $n(n+1)/2-(1+a+b) = ab$. This is easy to do since $1+a+b+ab=(1+a)(1+b)$.

So, when $n$ odd, choose $a=n-1,b=\frac{n-1}{2}$. E.g., for $n=7$, that gives $1\cdot 3\cdot 6=2+4+5+7$.

For $n$ even, $a=n,b=\frac{n-2}{2}$. For example, $n=6$ yields $a=6,b=2$ and $1\cdot 2\cdot 6=3+4+5$.

When $n<5$, $\{a,b,1\}$ are not distinct.

It's harder to do it in two elements in the product. Then you'd need $ab=n(n+1)/2-(a+b)$ or $(1+a)(1+b)=\frac{n^2+n+2}{2}$. So you'd need to factor $\frac{n^2+n+2}{2}$ into two distinct numbers $\leq n+1$.

You can do this for $n=17$, for example, then $\frac{n^2+n+2}{2}=154=11\cdot 14$. so $a=10,b=13$. Then $$10\cdot 13 =1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+11+12+14+15+16+17$$

The question came up about products of $4$ numbers. Let's still try to seek simple answers, so a product of the form $1\cdot 2\cdot a\cdot b = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}-(a+b+1+2)$, or:

$$2ab +a+b+3=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$ Multiply both sides by $2$ and you get:

$$(2a+1)(2b+1)+5 = n(n+1)$$

So we need to factor $n(n+1)-5$ into two distinct odd numbers $\leq 2n+1$. For example, $n=10$ then $n(n+1)-5=105=15\cdot 7$. So $a=3,b=7$. Then:

$$1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot 7 = 4+5+6+8+9+10$$

An example with the product containing $5$ elements, $n=20$ then:

$$1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4\cdot 8 = 5+6+7+9+10+\cdots + 20$$

An example with a product of $4$ numbers, none equal to $1$ (with $n=26$):

$$2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 11 = 1+4+6+7+8+9+10+12+\cdots +26$$

Another with $4$ in the product:

$$3\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdot 16 = \frac{58\cdot 59}{2} - (3+5+7+16)$$

We can get arbitrarily long product solutions. You can show that for $n=k!-k$, let $A=\frac{k!}{2}-k$, then:

$$1\cdot 2\cdot3\cdots k\cdot A = \frac{(k!-k)(k!-k+1)}{2}-(1+2+\cdots + k + A)$$

For example:

$$\begin{align}4!\cdot 8 &= \frac{20\cdot21}{2}-(1+2+3+4+8)\\
5!\cdot 55  &= \frac{115\cdot116}{2}-(1+2+3+4+5+55)\\
6!\cdot 354 &= \frac{714\cdot715}{2}-(1+2+3+4+5+6+354)\\
7!\cdot 2513 &= \frac{5033\cdot 5034}{2}-(1+2+3+4+5+6+7+2513)
\end{align}$$

More generally, if $\{x_i\}_{i=1,\cdot,m}$ are distinct positive integers with at least one even, let $S=\sum x_i$ and $P=\prod x_i$. Then if $S=\frac{k(k+1)}2$ for some $k$, then let $A=\frac{P}{2}-k$ and $n=P-k$. Then:

$$A\cdot \prod x_i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} - (x_1+\cdots + x_m + A)$$

For small collections of small values $x_i$ this doesn't always give a good $A$, but in most cases, it does.

For example $5+10=\frac{5(5+1)}2$. So $n=45$ and $A=20$, and you get $$5\cdot 10\cdot 20 = \frac{45\cdot 46}{2}-(5 + 10+20)$$

This means that we can always extend any $x_1,\cdots,x_m$ with a larger $x_{m+1}$ so that $\sum_{i=1}^{m+1} x_i$ is a triangular number, and then find the $A$ above. Indeed, we can write an explicit formula. If $S=\sum_{i=1}^m x_i$ and $P=\prod_{i=1}^m x_i$ then you can define $$\begin{align}x_{m+1}&=2S(S-1)\\x_{m+2}&=PS(S-1)-2S+1\\n&=2PS(S-1)-2S+1.\end{align}$$

Answer (score 6):

This can't be done for $n=4$.

One element of the product side won't do.
Two elements on the product side won't do. ($1*2=2\neq 7, 1*3=3\neq 8, 1*4\neq6, 2*3=6\neq 4, 2*4, nope$)
Surely it doesn't work for three elements on the product side.

It doesn't work.
For $n\geq 5$, certainly seems to be true. What I've found so far:

```
1*2*4 = 3+5    
1*2*6 = 3+4+5    
1*3*6 = 2+4+5+7    
1*3*8 = 2+4+5+6+7    
1*4*8 = 2+3+5+6+7+9    
6*7 = 1+2+3+4+5+8+9+10    
1*5*10 = 2+3+4+6+7+8+9+11    
1*5*12 = 2+3+4+6+7+8+9+10+11    
1*6*12 = 2+3+4+5+7+8+9+10+11+13    
1*6*14 = 2+3+4+5+7+8+9+10+11+12+13    
1*7*14 = 2+3+4+5+6+8+9+10+11+12+13+15    
1*7*16 = 2+3+4+5+6+8+9+10+11+12+13+14+15    
10*13 = 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+11+12+14+15+16+17    
1*8*18 = 2+3+4+5+6+7+9+10+11+12+13+14+15+16+17    
1*9*18 = 2+3+4+5+6+7+8+10+11+12+13+14+15+16+17+19    
1*9*20 = 2+3+4+5+6+7+8+10+11+12+13+14+15+16+17+18+19    
1*10*20 = 2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+11+12+13+14+15+16+17+18+19+21    
1*10*22 = 2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+11+12+13+14+15+16+17+18+19+20+21    
1*11*22 = 2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+12+13+14+15+16+17+18+19+20+21+23    
1*11*24 = 2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+12+13+14+15+16+17+18+19+20+21+22+23    
1*12*24 = 2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+13+14+15+16+17+18+19+20+21+22+23+25    
15*21 = 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12+13+14+16+17+18+19+20+22+23+24+25+26    
1*13*26 = 2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12+14+15+16+17+18+19+20+21+22+23+24+25+27    
1*13*28 = 2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12+14+15+16+17+18+19+20+21+22+23+24+25+26+27    
1*14*28 = 2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12+13+15+16+17+18+19+20+21+22+23+24+25+26+27+29    
1*14*30 = 2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12+13+15+16+17+18+19+20+21+22+23+24+25+26+27+28+29    
1*15*30 = 2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12+13+14+16+17+18+19+20+21+22+23+24+25+26+27+28+29+31    
1*15*32 = 2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12+13+14+16+17+18+19+20+21+22+23+24+25+26+27+28+29+30+31    
1*16*32 = 2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12+13+14+15+17+18+19+20+21+22+23+24+25+26+27+28+29+30+31+33    
1*16*34 = 2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12+13+14+15+17+18+19+20+21+22+23+24+25+26+27+28+29+30+31+32+33    
1*17*34 = 2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12+13+14+15+16+18+19+20+21+22+23+24+25+26+27+28+29+30+31+32+33+35    
22*28 = 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12+13+14+15+16+17+18+19+20+21+23+24+25+26+27+29+30+31+32+33+34+35+36    
21*31 = 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12+13+14+15+16+17+18+19+20+22+23+24+25+26+27+28+29+30+32+33+34+35+36+37    
1*18*38 = 2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12+13+14+15+16+17+19+20+21+22+23+24+25+26+27+28+29+30+31+32+33+34+35+36+37    
1*19*38 = 2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12+13+14+15+16+17+18+20+21+22+23+24+25+26+27+28+29+30+31+32+33+34+35+36+37+39    
1*19*40 = 2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12+13+14+15+16+17+18+20+21+22+23+24+25+26+27+28+29+30+31+32+33+34+35+36+37+38+39    
1*20*40 = 2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12+13+14+15+16+17+18+19+21+22+23+24+25+26+27+28+29+30+31+32+33+34+35+36+37+38+39+41    
1*20*42 = 2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12+13+14+15+16+17+18+19+21+22+23+24+25+26+27+28+29+30+31+32+33+34+35+36+37+38+39+40+41    
1*21*42 = 2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12+13+14+15+16+17+18+19+20+22+23+24+25+26+27+28+29+30+31+32+33+34+35+36+37+38+39+40+41+43    
1*21*44 = 2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12+13+14+15+16+17+18+19+20+22+23+24+25+26+27+28+29+30+31+32+33+34+35+36+37+38+39+40+41+42+43    
27*36 = 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12+13+14+15+16+17+18+19+20+21+22+23+24+25+26+28+29+30+31+32+33+34+35+37+38+39+40+41+42+43+44+45    
1*22*46 = 2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12+13+14+15+16+17+18+19+20+21+23+24+25+26+27+28+29+30+31+32+33+34+35+36+37+38+39+40+41+42+43+44+45    
1*23*46 = 2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12+13+14+15+16+17+18+19+20+21+22+24+25+26+27+28+29+30+31+32+33+34+35+36+37+38+39+40+41+42+43+44+45+47    
1*23*48 = 2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12+13+14+15+16+17+18+19+20+21+22+24+25+26+27+28+29+30+31+32+33+34+35+36+37+38+39+40+41+42+43+44+45+46+47
```

For $n=39$, I found these $7$ partitions:

```
1*19*38 = 2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12+13+14+15+16+17+18+20+21+22+23+24+25+26+27+28+29+30+31+32+33+34+35+36+37+39    
1*25*29 = 2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12+13+14+15+16+17+18+19+20+21+22+23+24+26+27+28+30+31+32+33+34+35+36+37+38+39    
3*7*35 = 1+2+4+5+6+8+9+10+11+12+13+14+15+16+17+18+19+20+21+22+23+24+25+26+27+28+29+30+31+32+33+34+36+37+38+39    
4*11*17 = 1+2+3+5+6+7+8+9+10+12+13+14+15+16+18+19+20+21+22+23+24+25+26+27+28+29+30+31+32+33+34+35+36+37+38+39    
5*10*15 = 1+2+3+4+6+7+8+9+11+12+13+14+16+17+18+19+20+21+22+23+24+25+26+27+28+29+30+31+32+33+34+35+36+37+38+39    
2*6*7*9 = 1+3+4+5+8+10+11+12+13+14+15+16+17+18+19+20+21+22+23+24+25+26+27+28+29+30+31+32+33+34+35+36+37+38+39    
1*3*4*7*9 = 2+5+6+8+10+11+12+13+14+15+16+17+18+19+20+21+22+23+24+25+26+27+28+29+30+31+32+33+34+35+36+37+38+39
```

Amazingly good question!

Comment: $n\geq 5$, now that's a whole new question.

Comment: I believe you have made a program. Can you test that there is only one solution for each case?

Comment: There isn't only one solution in each case. There is always a solution of the form $\{1,a,b\}$ for the product, but there might be a solution with two elements in the product. @PdotWang

Comment: For example, when $n=17,$ $$1\cdot 8\cdot 16 = 2+3+4+5+6+7+9+10+11+12+13+14+15+17$$ which is different from the answer above. @PdotWang

Comment: Question 1, would {a,b,c,d} be possible? Question 2, would {1,a,b} and {1,c,d} be possible"?

Comment: It would be interesting to find when there are $4$-element product solutions.

Comment: Those two questions are likely way to much to go over in comments. Could be a good second question, though. @PdotWang

Comment: Can you post it as a new one?

Comment: Thanks. We know there are multiple formations and multiple solutions, at least, and 1 is not necessary to stay in.

Comment: That was extensive !!

Comment: @PdotWang Four numbers in the product is possible. For $n=10$: $$1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot 7 = 4+5+6+8+9+10$$

Comment: Even five elements in the product occurs: $$1*2*3*4*5*6 = 7+8+9+ \dots +37+38$$

Comment: And yes there are many possible partitions, for example for $n=39$, I found $7$ different ones. I'll add them to my answer if you want to see them.

Comment: @ploosu2 I just found that you can get arbitrary number of numbers in the product.

Answer (score 3):

The sum of all the numbers is
$$
\sum_{k=1}^nk=\frac{n(n+1)}2\tag{1}
$$
We will find $a$ and $b$ so that
$$
\overbrace{\left(\sum_{k=1}^nk\right)-a-b-1}^{\text{sum of all but $a$, $b$, and $1$}}=\overbrace{\vphantom{\left(\sum_1^n\right)}1ab}^{\text{product}}\tag{2}
$$
That is, we need to find $a$ and $b$ so that
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{n(n+1)}2
&=\overbrace{ab}^{\text{product}}+\overbrace{a+b+1}^{\text{sum}}\\
&=(a+1)(b+1)\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
and $(3)$ can be solved using
$$
(a,b)=\left\{\begin{array}{}
\left(\frac{n-1}2,n-1\right)&\text{if $n$ is odd}\\
\left(n,\frac{n-2}2\right)&\text{if $n$ is even}\\
\end{array}\right.\tag{4}
$$
Thus, the product of $1$, $a$, and $b$ is the sum of the rest of the numbers from $1$ to $n$.

If $n\ge5$, then $a,b\ge2$ so that they don't interfere with $1$.

---

**Examples**

With $n=5$, $a=\frac{5-1}2=2$ and $b=5-1=4$ so $1\cdot2\cdot4=3+5$

With $n=6$, $a=6$ and $b=\frac{6-2}2=2$ so $1\cdot2\cdot6=3+4+5$

With $n=7$, $a=\frac{7-1}2=3$ and $b=7-1=6$ so $1\cdot3\cdot6=2+4+5+7$

With $n=8$, $a=8$ and $b=\frac{8-2}2=3$ so $1\cdot3\cdot8=2+4+5+6+7$

Answer (score 2):

For any odd $n$ and $n\geq5$ we can always find the item before the last one, and the item before the center item, and the first item. Then move those 3 items to the product set.

For example: $n=5$, move $1,2,4$. If: $n=7$, move $1,3,6$.

For any even $n$ and $n\geq6$ we can always find the last item, and the item just before the 2 center items, and the first item. Then move those 3 items to the product set. That is the solution.

For example: $n=6$, move $1,2,6$. If: $n=8$, move $1,3,8$.

for $n=3$, move 3. It seems that this is a special case.

To proof, we have the following relationships:

For: $n=odd$

Left: 
$${1\over2}n(n+1)-(n-1)-{(n-1)\over2}-1={1\over2}(n-1)^2$$
Right: 
$$(n-1){(n-1)\over2}={1\over2}(n-1)^2$$

For: $n=even$

Left: 
$${1\over2}n(n+1)-n-({n\over2}-1)-1={1\over2}n(n-2)$$
Right: 
$$n({n\over2}-1)={1\over2}n(n-2)$$

Note:
If we want to just give an answer to the question, then the above is OK. But in general, we need to know (1) How many items to move? (2) Which ones to move.  We cannot assume there must be 3 items, and 1 and (n-1) must be within the choices. Further we do not know if it is the only solution. We may need to proof.

Comment: for n=3, move 3. That is special, I think.

Comment: for n=7, move 1,3,6.

Comment: It is easy to prove. Left is the sum which is (n+1)n/2-(n-1)-(n-1)/2-1. Right is (n-1)(n-1)/2